# TSQL optimization of the execution plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL statement (that I can't post here). When I look at its execution plan I see most of the time is sitting in sorts, followed by index scans.

Is there anything I can do to lessen the time spend on sorts? an index of any kind? Anything I can do to lessen the time spent in index scans?

[image]

Comment: If you can't post the script or at least break it down into chunks that *can* be posted, honestly, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustered index scan is essentially a table scan, where every row in the table is being examined.

You're probably missing an index on that table for this query... look at the fields that you're filtering by / joining on, and add indexes to these columns.

These indexes will also likely prevent the nested loop / sort operations as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering out loud here, but do you have any ranking functions involved in your query? I ask because I'm seeing segment operators right after the sort and I usually see those if I'm doing something like ROW_NUMBER() or RANK(). All such operators require an order by in the OVER clause, so if your data isn't already ordered by that metric (i.e. it isn't ordered that way on the table/index that the data is getting pulled from), then the engine is going to have to sort the data to get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want people to take you seriously, and especially if you want accurate responses and help from you questions, then you MUST INCLUDE specific information. If anybody is going to help they NEED sufficient information to be able to reproduce your conditions so that they themselves verify that what the suggest actually does help. Believe it or not, the people that respond are so great (thannk to everyone that helps), that they usually DO test what they say. If you have code resttrictions because its work related. You should have enough understanding to be able to create a similar example with other tables and columns to show the problem without compromising the code.

To the Point, you samples do the following
1) Nested Loop:
2) Sort

In this case the SORT is done because the result of the (Nested Loop) is not ORDERED the way it is need. Being that the source of the (Nested Loop) is the top table (Clustered Index Scan) it is read in the order of the (Clusted Inex Key) which obviously IS NOT the same as the NEEDED SORT.

If the field that is actually being sorted on ss part of an KEY of an INDEX and all needed columns of the query are INCLUDED in the index, then the it should use an "Index Scan" on that index which should ALREADY be ordered by the ORDER BY KEY and the SORT could be avoided.

I ran some tests on this and apparently SQL Server DOES use the Index (as expected) but STILL performs the SORT (not as expeceted since the data stream is ALREADY SORTED). This could be something that should be reported to MS since the optimizer SHOULD recognize this.

Hope this helps..